# Why does my custom directive shows parameters error when they are receiving them?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, directive

I made a custom conditional directive to determine if a user is allowed or not by the role.

```
Blade::if('isAllow', function($type, $my_role_id) {
    //dd($type, $my_role_id);
    $rol = Role::where('name', $type)->first();
    return $my_role_id == $rol->id? true : false;
});
```

I use it this way.

```
@isAllow('Requestor', Auth()->user()->role_id) All @elseisAllow Reviewed @endisAllow
```

If into the directive, I put a dd() to see the values, it shows them to me without much problem.

[image]

But, when I want to use it in the template, it shows me the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

I can't find a solution to explain me why is not getting any param when it does. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wrote **@elseisAllow** which is close to the meaning of **else if** and after @elseisAllow you did not provide arguments so you are getting error .
if you don't want to check another condition just use **@else**

but if you want to check more you should provide arguments that would be something like this : @elseisAllow('Author',auth()->user()->role_id)